# Rendering host container returns 500

Tags: nextjs, xm-cloud, horizon

Whenever I try to access my local Sitecore instance in the Pages editor, it shows an error: `Connection to rendering host http://rendering:3000/api/editing/render failed with the following error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error`

And when I check the rendering host, via the `PUBLIC_URL` or by running `curl http://rendering:3000` in the CM container’s terminal, it shows this error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.processResponse
<unknown>
<unknown>
Async.runInAsyncScope
```

Has anyone encountered this as well?

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to HTTP binding. See if it works for you.

> This happened because the `URL` in `SITECORE_API_HOST` in my `.env` file was using an `HTTPS` connection. When I added an `HTTP` binding to my site and changed the URL to HTTP it worked.

**Credit**: [Guide To Fixing Setup Errors: Sitecore Headless SXA, Next.js, XM Cloud Dev](https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/troubleshooting-errors-for-sitecore-headless-sxa-next-js-xm-cloud-setup)

Hope it help!